# librosa installation via pip failing

Tags: python-3.x, llvm, librosa

Python version is  3.4.2

```
(env) ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/my_proj$ pip install librosa
```

> Collecting librosa Collecting joblib>=0.12 (from librosa)   Using
>   cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/91/d217cec1fe6eac525ca964cd67e4f79b1d4ce68b64cb82d0b9ae1af2311e/joblib-0.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting numba>=0.38.0 (from librosa) Collecting
>   scikit-learn!=0.19.0,>=0.14.0 (from librosa)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/bc/3f579cb9c58e3fdc7d4d66e9b47822ee5e6679dcf72d206831c77d8b6554/scikit_learn-0.20.0-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl Collecting scipy>=0.14.0 (from librosa)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/ad/64a741013cbdf1c364779e54d7413554c4f6c8fd8d790a8c805f593d10ea/scipy-1.1.0-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl Collecting resampy>=0.2.0 (from librosa) Requirement already
>   satisfied: six>=1.3 in ./env/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from
>   librosa) (1.11.0) Collecting decorator>=3.0.0 (from librosa)   Using
>   cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/bb/a24838832ba35baf52f32ab1a49b906b5f82fb7c76b2f6a7e35e140bac30/decorator-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.0 in
>   ./env/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from librosa) (1.15.2) Requirement
>   already satisfied: audioread>=2.0.0 in
>   ./env/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from librosa) (2.1.6) Collecting
>   llvmlite>=0.25.0dev0 (from numba>=0.38.0->librosa)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/6c/4711620ae28b8aaa8d731e519ead648359d71c1de0c709e408671236b23a/llvmlite-0.25.0.tar.gz
>   Building wheels for collected packages: llvmlite   Running setup.py
>   bdist_wheel for llvmlite ... error   Complete output from command
>   /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/my_proj/env/bin/python3.4
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d
>   /private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-wheel-me97wgqk
>   --python-tag cp34:   running bdist_wheel   /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/my_proj/env/bin/python3.4
>   /private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
>   LLVM version... Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/ffi/build.py",
>   line 105, in main_posix
>         out = subprocess.check_output([llvm_config, '--version'])
>       File "/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py",
>   line 607, in check_output
>         with Popen(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, **kwargs) as process:
>       File "/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py",
>   line 858, in **init**
>         restore_signals, start_new_session)
>       File "/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py",
>   line 1456, in _execute_child
>         raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'llvm-config'
>        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>        Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/ffi/build.py",
>   line 167, in 
>         main()
>       File "/private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/ffi/build.py",
>   line 161, in main
>         main_posix('osx', '.dylib')
>       File "/private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/ffi/build.py",
>   line 108, in main_posix
>         "to the path for llvm-config" % (llvm_config,))   RuntimeError: llvm-config failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for
>   llvm-config   error: command
>   '/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/my_proj/env/bin/python3.4'
>   failed with exit status 1
>        ----------------------------------------   Failed building wheel for llvmlite   Running setup.py clean for llvmlite Failed to build
>   llvmlite Installing collected packages: joblib, llvmlite, numba,
>   scipy, scikit-learn, resampy, decorator, librosa   Running setup.py
>   install for llvmlite ... error
>       Complete output from command /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/my_proj/env/bin/python3.4
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-record-g2lb1vmw/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/my_proj/env/include/site/python3.4/llvmlite:
>       running install
>       running build
>       got version from file /private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/llvmlite/_version.py
>   {'full': '9af98a608a49278dbc4ce5dc743152f2341b6a87', 'version':
>   '0.25.0'}
>       running build_ext
>       /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/my_proj/env/bin/python3.4
>   /private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
>       LLVM version... Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/ffi/build.py",
>   line 105, in main_posix
>           out = subprocess.check_output([llvm_config, '--version'])
>         File "/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py",
>   line 607, in check_output
>           with Popen(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, **kwargs) as process:
>         File "/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py",
>   line 858, in **init**
>           restore_signals, start_new_session)
>         File "/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py",
>   line 1456, in _execute_child
>           raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
>       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'llvm-config'
>
> ```
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/ffi/build.py",
> ```
>
> line 167, in 
>           main()
>         File "/private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/ffi/build.py",
>   line 161, in main
>           main_posix('osx', '.dylib')
>         File "/private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/ffi/build.py",
>   line 108, in main_posix
>           "to the path for llvm-config" % (llvm_config,))
>       RuntimeError: llvm-config failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config
>       error: command '/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/my_proj/env/bin/python3.4'
>   failed with exit status 1
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command "/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/my_proj/env/bin/python3.4
> ```
>
> -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-record-g2lb1vmw/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/my_proj/env/include/site/python3.4/llvmlite"
>   failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/wb/85mzqshn0gv54rd1jnpgn6tm0000gn/T/pip-install-7yb_7yfx/llvmlite/

I installed  `llvm` too but still result is the same

```
(env) ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/my_proj$ brew reinstall llvm
```

> ==> Reinstalling llvm 
>   ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/llvm-7.0.0.high_sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
>
> ################################################################## 100.0%
>
> ==> Pouring llvm-7.0.0.high_sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
>
> ==> Caveats To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:   LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib
>   -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
>
> llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
>   because macOS already provides this software and installing another
>   version in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
>
> If you need to have llvm first in your PATH run:   echo 'export
>   PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
>
> For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:   export
>   LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"   export
>   CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"
>
> ==> Summary   /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/7.0.0: 2,727 files, 1.4GB

Answer (score 1):

After reading the error log carefully, realised we need llvm version 6 instead of llvm version 7 which I had by default,

**Step 1:** `brew install llvm@6`

**Step 2:** Added the following to `~/.bashrc`

```
export LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/local/opt/llvm@6/bin/llvm-config
```

**Step 3:** Reload `~/.bashrc`

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your questions when you figure them out. It really makes a difference.

Comment: `Warning: No available formula with the name "llvm@6". Did you mean llvm, llvm@9, llvm@8, llvm@7, llvm@14, llvm@13, llvm@12, llvm@11 or wllvm?`