# Error while installing turicreate using pip ...while building wheel for llvmlite

Tags: python, pip, llvmlite, turi

I am trying to install turicreate using `pip install turicreate` but receive the error below. I don't know what this error is telling me to do.

Someone in the comments asked if I installed llvm correctly. How would I do this?

I tried upgrading Scipy using `pip install --upgrade scipy` but this did not help.

```
 Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/harshavardhanhr/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-wheel-e0QD2K
       cwd: /private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/
  Complete output (11 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  /Users/harshavardhanhr/venv/bin/python /private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
  LLVM version... Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 168, in <module>
      main()
    File "/private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 162, in main
      main_posix('osx', '.dylib')
    File "/private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 109, in main_posix
      "to the path for llvm-config" % (llvm_config,))
  RuntimeError: llvm-config failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config
  error: command '/Users/harshavardhanhr/venv/bin/python' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Failed to build llvmlite
ERROR: tensorflow 2.1.0 has requirement scipy==1.2.2; python_version < "3", but you'll have scipy 1.2.3 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: llvmlite, funcsigs, singledispatch, numba, resampy, mock, opt-einsum, h5py, keras-applications, gast, keras-preprocessing, pyasn1, rsa, cachetools, pyasn1-modules, google-auth, idna, chardet, urllib3, certifi, requests, werkzeug, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, google-auth-oauthlib, futures, grpcio, absl-py, markdown, tensorboard, backports.weakref, tensorflow-estimator, functools32, astor, termcolor, wrapt, google-pasta, tensorflow, decorator, python-dateutil, pytz, pandas, turicreate
    Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/harshavardhanhr/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-record-Tq46YM/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/harshavardhanhr/venv/include/site/python2.7/llvmlite
         cwd: /private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running install
    running build
    got version from file /private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.32.0', 'full': '26059d238f4ba23dff74703dd27168591d889edd'}
    running build_ext
    /Users/harshavardhanhr/venv/bin/python /private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
    LLVM version... Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 168, in <module>
        main()
      File "/private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 162, in main
        main_posix('osx', '.dylib')
      File "/private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 109, in main_posix
        "to the path for llvm-config" % (llvm_config,))
    RuntimeError: llvm-config failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config
    error: command '/Users/harshavardhanhr/venv/bin/python' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/harshavardhanhr/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-install-00VSH7/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/8s/14fz39z503n7hqftf_yg1nyr0000gn/T/pip-record-Tq46YM/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/harshavardhanhr/venv/include/site/python2.7/llvmlite Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What is your os, python version and what is the command you used for the instllation. Please also use a minimal amount of time to format your question appropriately

Comment: This is the gist of the problem: "*tensorflow 2.1.0 has requirement scipy==1.2.2; python_version < "3", but you'll have scipy 1.2.3*". Install a different version of `scipy` or use `pip install --upgrade` to make `pip` install proper versions automatically.

Comment: @phd I think ` RuntimeError: llvm-config failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config error` is the main error here.

Comment: Have you installed `llvm` prpoerly?

Comment: please construct your question properly, don't just randomly throw an error message without any context

Comment: @FlyingTeller How do you do that?

Comment: [This answer is helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52646224/6331353). It shows how to install `llvm` properly.

Answer (score 0):

For the second error, you are going to need to install *scipy version 1.2.2* specifically.

```
pip install 'scipy==1.2.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the important part of your error, hidden right in the middle

```
RuntimeError: llvm-config failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config
```

This probably means you have to set `LLVM_CONFIG` in your `~/.bashrc`, something like

```
export LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/local/opt/llvm@9/bin/llvm-config
```

After doing that, remember to source it

`source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue with llvmlite when I was trying to install `tslearn` with `python3.9`. After so much struggling with different versions and github communities, I came up with the solution to install the `llvmlite` with `python3.8` which works pretty fine. I tried installing using `python3.9` and also `python2.7` but they probably have some version supporting issues when installing `llvmlite`.